# Dashed /^/ in xy package

Tags: xy-pic, punctuation

I am trying to make the following arc between two objects using the `/^/` but I need it to be dashed my matrix is as follow:

```
\xymatrix{
    &0\ar@{-->}[r]&0'\ar@{-->}[l]\\
    &x\ar@{->}[u]\ar@{->}[r]&x'\ar@{->}[u]\\
    &n\ar@{-->}[r]\ar@{->}[u]&n'\ar@{-->}[l]\\
    &b\ar@/^/[uuu]\ar@{-->}[r]&b'\ar@{-->}[l]
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
\ar@/^/@{-->}[uuu]
```

seems to give what's expected. You may also try

```
\ar@/^15pt/@{-->}[uuu]
```

to increase the bending of the curved arrow.

```
\xymatrix{
    &0\ar@{-->}[r]&0'\ar@{-->}[l]\\
    &x\ar@{->}[u]\ar@{->}[r]&x'\ar@{->}[u]\\
    &n\ar@{-->}[r]\ar@{->}[u]&n'\ar@{-->}[l]\\
    &b\ar@/^15pt/@{-->}[uuu]\ar@{-->}[r]&b'\ar@{-->}[l]
    }
```